# Compare two input strings and concatenate the smaller into the larger and return the full string length MIPS

Tags: mips

I have a MIPS programs with procedure that get two input strings as arguments and just concatenate them into one. I want to compare them and put the larger string into the smaller and print the full string length.

Here is the code that i have write till now:

```
.data
first: .space 255 #255 bytes for first string
second: .space 255 #255 bytes for second stringfull: .space 512 #255 bytes for first string
.text
main:
    la $a0,first
    li $a1,255
    li $v0,8
    syscall
    la $a0,second
    li $a1,255
    li $v0,8
    syscall
    move $s0,$ra
    la $a0,first
    la $a1,second
    la $a2,full
    jal strcpy
    move $ra,$s0

    add $a0,$a1,$zero 
    li $v0, 1       
    syscall

#display a new-line
    li $a0,10
    li $v0,11   
    syscall

#exit
    jr $ra

strcpy:
    li $t8 10 #store newline in $t8
    slt $s2,$a1,$a0
    beq $s2,$zero,sCopyFirst

if_pocetok:
    add $a3,$a1,$a0
    add $a0,$a1,$zero
    add $a1,$a3,$zero
    beq $zero,$zero,sCopyFirst  

#loop through first string and copy to output string
sCopyFirst:

    lb   $t0 0($a0)
    beq  $t0 $zero sCopySecond #exit loop on null byte
    beq  $t0 $t8 sCopySecond  #exit loop on new-line
    sb   $t0 0($a2)
    addi $a0 $a0 1
    addi $a2 $a2 1
    b sCopyFirst



#loop through second string and copy to output string 
sCopySecond:

    lb   $t0 0($a1)
    beq  $t0 $zero sDone #exit on null byte
    beq  $t0 $t8 sDone   #exit on new-line
    sb   $t0 0($a2)
    addi $a1 $a1 1
    addi $a2 $a2 1
    b sCopySecond

sDone:
    add $a1,$zero,$zero
    sb $zero,0($a2) #null terminate string
    addi $t1,$zero,0
    loop:
    lbu $t2, 0($a2)          
    beq $t2, $zero, exit    

    addi $a2, $a2, 1        
    addi $a1, $a1, 1    
    jal loop
exit:
    jr $ra
```

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry I am new here..... 
This is the project i want help with:
Write a MIPS procedure which finds the length of two separate input arguments (type string). Then, the longer string should be concatenated to the shorter string, and its length should be calculated and printed.
Write a main program for testing the procedure, through the following steps: entering strings from the keyboard, invoking the procedure and printing the length on a screen. ”

Comment: That's your assignment. And we see what you've written so far. What is not working the way you expect? What don't you understand?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815882/mips-how-to-add-one-string-to-another/36817463#36817463